# Android - animating text views in xml one by one

Tags: android, android-studio, animation

[image]i have one activity that has 3 text view.  i want to animate these text views one by one.
first txt1 come from bottom to middle  then txt2 come 10dp under txt1 and finally txt3.

please guide me how implement it

Comment: Please be more descriptive about the question and try to include screenshots or mockups or wireframes of the screens and text views to understand the question better.

Comment: i updated it Shaukh mohammed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with translate and alpha animation.

Create XML file named ***down_to_top.xml*** in **anim** folder (create one in you "**res**" folder if it's not present)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="700">
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="50%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1" />
</set>
```

In your activity

1. Initialize your text views to **tv1,tv2,tv3**
2. Copy these three functions in your activity.
3. Call **setAnimation()** in your onCreate function of activity

   ```
    private fun setAnimation() {
    tv2.visibility = View.INVISIBLE // initially keeping t2 invisible
    tv3.visibility = View.INVISIBLE // initially keeping t3 invisible

    // Creating obect of Animation 
    val anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, 
     R.anim.down_to_up)
    //Listener to get callback when animation of tv1 ends
    val animListener1 = object : Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation) {}

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {
            // when animation of first TextView ends we start 
         animation of textView 2 and make it visible 
            animateSecondView()
            tv2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation) {}
    }

    anim.setAnimationListener(animListener1)
    tv1.startAnimation(anim)
    } 

   private fun animateSecondView() {
    val anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, 
     R.anim.down_to_up)

    //Listener to get callback when animation of tv2 ends
    val animListener2 = object : Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation) {}

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {
    // when animation of TextView 2 ends we start animation of  
     textView 3 and make it visible 
            animateThirdView()
            tv3.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation) {}
    }
    anim.setAnimationListener(animListener2)
    tv2.startAnimation(anim)
   }

   private fun animateThirdView() {
   val anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity,R.anim.down_to_up)
   tv3.startAnimation(anim)
    }
   ```

You will have a [result like this](https://gfycat.com/miserlybigheartedcowbird).

Comment: thx for ur complete answre. it is exactly what i wanted.  but i can not understand logic of ur code. can u explain little for me.

Comment: Sure. So I will edit my answer and some comments over there for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways you can achieve animations in android

- [Move a view using animation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reposition-view)

  A good place to start with the recommended way of writing animations in Android.
- [AndroidViewAnimations](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations)

  A beginner-friendly pre-made animations library for Android
- [Animate all the things. Transitions in Android](https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50)

  A very good article explaining how to implement different types of translations on Views

Above mentioned links are a great place to get started.